# Holomorphic function on $D\cap \{z:Im(z)>0\}$

Tags: complex-analysis, functions

Let $f$ be a holomorphic function on $D^+:=D\cap \{z:Im(z)>0\}$ where $D=D(0,1)$ is the unit disc, and continuous on $\overline{D\cap \{z:Im(z)>0\}}$ and $f=0$ on $(-1,1). $

I would like to prove that $f$ is identically equals to $0$.

First of all using maximum principle we have for all $z\in D^+:$ $$\vert f(z)\vert\le \sup\{\vert f(z)\vert:z\in \partial D^+\}.$$

I guess now is to prove that the concentration on $(-1,1)$ is sufficient to conclude.

Some remarks:

1. $(-1,1)$ is connected so I must used it somewhere
2. I tried also to argue by contradiction, if $f$ is not identically equals to $0$ then the zero of $f$ noted $Z(f)$ is a closed discret subset. So that there exist $r>0$ such that $f$ contains only one zero on $D(0,r)\subset D^+$ not sure that helps.

How can I continue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $g:D \to \mathbb C$ by

$g(z):=f(z)$, if $z \in D^{+}$   and $g(z):=\overline{f(\overline{z})}$, if $z \in D\cap \{z:Im(z) \le 0\}$.

By Schwarz's reflection principle, $g$ is holomorphic on $D$.

Furthermore we have $g=0 $ on $(-1,1)$

Your turn !

Comment: ah!! You use the proof of Schwarz's reflection principle (I just check the principle). Really nice, now $g=0$ on $(-1,1)\subset D$ so that by the zeros isolated principle $g=0$ on $D$ and then $f$ is zero on $D^+.$ Right?

Comment: Yes ! Well ! Right !